# how centreon monitor switch traffic

Tags: snmp

*I have a program about to monitor the traffic of our company's switches.And we choose the centreon to make a solution.But there have less reference about the centreon program.And I only find blow link about to set the monitor.* [Centreon - Add Host or Router and monitor bandwidth utilization | Let's Explain](http://letusexplain.blogspot.kr/2013/11/add-hostrouter-in-centreon-monitoring.html)

But when I get to "Check_Centreon_SNMP_Traffic" Topic. I have a question in how to set the "Argument Example",it must to set the switch port.But i havn't learn the Macro.Does anyone have experience with centreon monitor the traffic.Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the [Centreon Forum](https://forum.centreon.com/)?

Comment: @chen, are you asking how that field needs to be specified for that particular script ? If so, the important part is that the options passed to the script are -n and -i. The "-i" allows you to specify a specific interface, and the -n allows you to provide the name of the interface rather than its index. You can retrieve interface names and/or index numbers by using an SNMP tool to retrieve the RFC 1213 interfaces table.